# Android: What is faster surface view or canvas with thread runnable

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app using Android 2.3 that has a graph and a gauge in the same activity that displays vehicle data.  The graph runs in a background thread and uses the runnable class.  The graph is updated using runOnUiThread() calling the invalidate() function.

The gauge uses a surface view.  The thread for the surface view does not use a runnable.

The graph "flickers" when running on an android device.  I've used the trace view to analyze the program but only saw one improvement I could do.

My questions is: Would it be worth the work to convert the graph code to use a surface view?

By the way, I've researched stack overflow and I've read it's a "no-no" not to use two surface views in an activity.

Comment: i think using the surface view with openGL would be the best. you could also use renderscript, but it's deprecated for visual stuff.